# How to retrieve and display relationship data in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables in the database. `orders, products`, and `order_product` table. this is how they look like in my `phpmyAdmin` https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOZVQ.jpg
I would like sellers to see orders placed by buyers in their view (`dashboard`). Also, buyers to be able to see their orders in their view.

Here are my relationships in models

**User.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'Seller'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 
    ];

    //public function isSeller() {
    //   return $this->seller;
    //}

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Products_model::class);
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'seller_id', 'product_id');
    }

    public function orderFromBuyers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(OrderProduct::class, Products_model::class, 'buyer_id', 'product_id');
    }

    public function orderFromSellers()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(OrderProduct::class, Products_model::class, 'seller_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

**OrderProduct.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'order_product';
    protected $fillable = ['order_id', 'buyer_id', 'seller_id','product_id', 'quantity'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Products_model');
    }

    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'buyer_id');
    }

    public function seller()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'seller_id');
    }

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

**Order.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    //protected $table = 'orders';
    protected $fillable =  [
        'shipping_email', 'shipping_name', 'shipping_city', 'shipping_phone', 'billing_subtotal', 'billing_total',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products_model')->withPivot('quantity');
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct', 'order_id');
    }
}
```

**Seller Function**

```
// Seller Orders 
public function viewOrders(User $user)
{

    // $products = Products_model::where('seller_id', '=', $user->id)->get();
    // all sells
    $sells = $user->orderFromSellers();
    dd($sells);
    return view('orders')->with(compact('sells'));
}
```

**Buyer Function**

```
//Buyer Orders
public function myOrders()
{
    $cart = session();
    $orders = Auth::user()->orders;
    $orders->transform(function($order, $key) {
        dd($orders);
        $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
        return $order;
    });
    return view('myOrders', ['orders' => $orders]);
}
```

Right now it shows nothing. Any help on how to solve this will be appreciated.

**Products_model**

```
protected $table='products';
protected $primaryKey='id';
protected $fillable=['seller_id','pro_name','pro_price','pro_info','image','stock','category_id '];
```

Comment: Hello @joh can I see your Products_model database fields?

Comment: I have already update question with products_model @hasan05

Comment: There is no primary field? like id?

Comment: @hasan05 what do you mean there is no primary field?

Comment: @hasan05 if you look at this link, it shows all fields in products table https://imgur.com/a/Ud9e2Hh

Comment: You are using $sells = $user->orderFromSellers(); in Seller Function. It returns relation instance not result, Just remove () and use dd($user->orderFromSellers); instead.

Comment: @umar_ when i dd($user->orderFromSellers); it shows `Collection {#283 ▼
  #items: []
}`

Comment: It means it is returning data. If you don't know how dd() works just try these two lines
echo "<pre>";
die($user->orderFromSellers);
You'll get clear image if it's returning any data or not.

Comment: @umar_ it returns empty array that is what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing two function.

```
public function orderFromBuyers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Products_model::class, OrderProduct::class,  'buyer_id', 'product_id');
}
public function orderFromSellers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Products_model::class, OrderProduct::class, 'seller_id', 'product_id');
}
```

Or the two will be more better. Add these two functions to User model.

```
public function allOrderFromBuyers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class, 'buyer_id');
}

public function allOrderFromSellers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(OrderProduct::class, 'seller_id');
}
```

Then change this to,

```
// Seller Orders 
public function viewOrders(User $user)
{
    // all sells
    $sells = $user->allOrderFromSellers();
    dd($sells);
    return view('orders')->with(compact('sells'));
}
```

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. try now.

Comment: did you update anything? because I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: hey @Hasan05 can you help me see why it's not showing?

Comment: I can, But, it will be a big changes in my way and also get some more time. Try more 12 hrs. If you cannot able then knock me. I will debug it for you.

Comment: This is the second day trying to see what's wrong. if you can spare some of your time to help will be great.@Hasan05

Comment: I already said, it will take a huge time. and now i am bg with my project. thats why i asked for around 12 hr. :(

Comment: one suggetion i can give you. that is, reformat the model and relations. and this time, just dont use `hasManyThrough` relation.

Comment: Okay thanks, i will keep working on it. if i fail to solve it, i will tag you.

Comment: hey @Hasan05 yesterday i used this `$orders = auth()->user()->allOrderFromBuyers()->with('orders')->get();` and i was able to get the properties of orderproduct table like this https://imgur.com/a/kH0Lara. But i can't get other properties like price, name of products etc.